# Strange output of this C program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int i;
char c;
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        scanf("%d",&c);
        printf("%d",i);
}
printf("\n");
}
```

I thought it will print 0 1 2 3 4 but it didn't.
What's the reason of the strange output?

Comment: what is the output? and why do you think it is strange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program exhibits [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): The type of `&c` (char *) does not correspond to the type of the scanf arg (`%d` wants a signed int *).

What is probably happening is that the scanf is writing 4 bytes to the memory location starting at the address of `c`. Which is only 1 byte long, so the other 3 bytes overwrite the first 3 bytes of `i`'s value. On a little-endian system, that would effectively set `i` to whatever integer value you enter shifted right by 8 bits.

But, of course, the behavior is undefined. Next time you compile this code, it *could* do something completely different. A different compiler, or the same compiler with different options, could keep `i` in a register (where scanf cannot overwrite it) (but it might instead smash the return address on the stack, causing a crash when the program ends), or it could put the values on the stack in the opposite order (same deal), or it could leave 4 bytes on the stack for `c` (causing no unexpected behavior), or it could detect the situation and abort with an error, or it could even [make demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Answer (score 5):

**[Undefined Behaviour](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior)**.

You're attempting to read an `int` (the `"%d"` in the scanf call) into an object of type `char` (the `c`). Don't do that!

Comment: And although undefined, the behavior here is most probably that either `i` or some other stuff is overwritten by scanf, leading to an incorrect value of `i` or a total screw-up of the program and the random creation of animated GIF unicorns.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading into `c` but printing `i`, so you will see 01234.  You probably mean to print `c`.  But that's not enough.  `c` should be declared int because you are reading with format `"%d"`, which expects an int.  Either use format `hhd` or change `c` to type int

Answer (score -1):

```
scanf("%d",&c);
```

should be

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

btw. It will ask you to input value for c in every iteration and then it will print one value of i. What are you getting?

Answer (score -1):

> What's the reason of the strange output?

It's because you havn't used scanf properly. When you use "%d", you have to give scanf a pointer to an int, but you gave it a pointer to a char.

Change your `char c` to `int c`

(You should also check functions for errors. e.g. scanf will return EOF on end of input. It will also return the count of assigned values. Since you have given it 1 value, `&c` , you should check that scanf returns 1. If it does not,  something bad might have happened)